# Manter uma TextView Alterada mesmo apos fechar o app

Tags: android

Galera tô fazendo um aplicativo para gestão financeira, controle de gastos para a faculdade, é minha primeira experiencia com android studio e a linguagem java, mas já estou evoluindo bastante, preciso manter alterada a TextView de saldo do usuario, a mesma no OnCreate possui um Método que traz de uma outra activity um valor para ser tratado de acordo com oq o usuario informa no caso gasto ou ganho, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando recria a solução acabo perdendo o saldo, gostaria de uma ajuda pra manter o valor da TextView mesmo apos ela ser fechada.
segue a baixo o onCreate da minha Acitivity onde tem o metodo e a TextView que desejo manter.
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        txtSaldo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSaldo);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
           String txt = bundle.getString("txt");
           String teste=bundle.getString("teste");

```
           if(teste!=null) {
               if (teste.contains("+")) {
                   v2 = txt;
                   double vb = Double.parseDouble(v2);
                   v1 = txtSaldo.getText().toString();
                   double va = Double.parseDouble(v1);
                   double total = vb + va;
                   resultado = Double.toString(total);

                   txtSaldo.setText(resultado);

               } else {
                   v2 = txt;
                   double vb = Double.parseDouble(v2);
                   v1 = txtSaldo.getText().toString();
                   double va = Double.parseDouble(v1);
                   double total = va - vb;
                   resultado = Double.toString(total);
                   txtSaldo.setText(resultado);
               }
           }


    }


    smartTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.smartTabLayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(),
            FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                    .add("Últimos lançamentos", ListaFragment.class)
                    .add("Histórico Mês", HistoricoFragment.class)
                    .add("Gráficos", GraficoFragment.class)
                    .create()
    );
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);


}
```

Comment: Você precisa salvar essa informação em um banco de dados e recuperá-lá ao iniciar o app. Pesquise sobre persistência de dados em Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de várias formas, as mais viáveis é criar um banco de dados Sqlite, ou salvar em uma variável do tipo SharedPreferences, que é muito usado para sessão.
 Como o método do Sqlite é mais complexo e longo você vai dar uma pesquisada, pra começar pode ir nesse link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-crud-com-android-studio-e-sqlite/32815

E aqui vou demonstrar como usar o sharedPrefs:

Ela é declarada da segunte forma:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("VALOR_TXT", seuedittext.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

E para resgatá-la basta fazer o seguinte:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
String algumaString = pref.getString("VALOR_TXT", "");
```